# Executing JUnit test case for Java standalone that takes command line inputs

Tags: java, junit, command-line-arguments

I have wrote a Java standalone application that takes input command line arguments. How to test it using JUnit test cases?

Comment: Same way as anything else, but unless you're testing parameter passing, you should be testing the actual logic, e.g., methods within the app. If parameter marshalling is properly isolated, that can be tested as well. Otherwise you call main with parameters like any other static method.

Answer (score 3):

Just call your `main()` method from JUnit. However, since `main()` does not return anything, you can't easily write any assertions (you must depend on side effects).

So for the sake of simplicity and maintainability of your tests, separate `main()` method with parameter parsing from the actual logic. Test `main()` alone with mocked logic to test parameter parsing and test business logic separately. Your business logic will have well defined, strongly typed interfaces, making it much easier to test and understand.

Also this step will reduce coupling and increase readability.

Comment: On the similar lines I was able to achieve the JUnit tests on Standalone java with arguments. I have created mock main method. In my case it does System.exit(with status code) and return text for good arguments. So there is no way for Junit to read this outcome, but I monitor the log output/console.